# multiple embedded process engine instances using shared database across multiple applications in camunda?

Tags: camunda

Hello every one I am trying my hands on camunda and would like to say so far the tool seems awesome, but one thing I can't figure out is what shall happen when I bootstrap a process engine (with the same name) across multiple different applications. such as imagine this code is written in many applications but the camunda database url is same in processes.xml which basically means same processes.xml is read for each process application.

```
// instantiate the process application
MyProcessApplication processApplication = new MyProcessApplication();

// deploy the process application
processApplication.deploy();

    // interact with the process engine
    ProcessEngine processEngine = BpmPlatform.getDefaultProcessEngine();
    processEngine.getRuntimeService().startProcessInstanceByKey(...);
    
    // undeploy the process application
    processApplication.undeploy();
    Where the class MyProcessApplication could look like this:
    
    @ProcessApplication(
        name="my-app",
        deploymentDescriptors={"path/to/my/processes.xml"}
    )
    public class MyProcessApplication extends EmbeddedProcessApplication {
    
    }
```

now if I instantiate a process instance via the repository service in one application will I be able to reference it another application if I query for it via the repository service? cause I think repository service is accessed via `ProcessEngine` and surely the process engine object in another application is different from the one that started the process instance? right? but the database is shared so will process instance be available? need help as I cant get my head around this may be i am missing some fundamental knowledge so please do enlighten me.